# invoking lable text from another class in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently updating my Form with this code within the `public partial class Form1 : Form`

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    Intellisale_Lastprocessed_Item_Label.Text = "example"
}
```

since I have tons of UI elements I would rather get all my ui update code into another class.

Therefore I built the class "UiUpdate".
unfortunately from within this class i receive the message:
"Form 1 does not contain a definition for Intellisale_Lastprocessed_Item_Label"

[image]

Probably I have overlooked something really easy but I have not found the answer yet.

EDIT:

Due to the Suggestions I changed my code to the following:

```
class UiUpdate
{
    public void UpdateIntellisale(Form1 form)
    {
        form.Intellisale_Lastprocessed_Item_Label.text = "example";
    }
}
```

unfortunately i still receive the message that no definition for the lable is available

Update 2:

as mentioned, the lables were defined private within the designer

Comment: It can not work. You call the type of your class Form (Form1) and not the instance of this class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a `static` reference to the `Form1` *class*, not to a particular *instance* of that class.  Pass the instance you need to your method:

```
public void UpdateIntellisale(Form1 form)
{
    form.Intellisale_Lastprocessed_Item_Label.Text = "test";
    // etc...
}
```

When you call it from your form you would pass it the reference to your form.  Which may be `this` if called from the form itself.  Basically you need your helper class/method to know what form it's working with.

Comment: I tried that but still says that no definition could be found

Comment: @JulianBechtold: What specifically did you try and what specifically was the error?  Include the code (not pictures of the code, but the actual code) in your question.

Comment: @JulianBechtold: What is the *exact* error message?  Also, is the property `public`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the object of `Form1` class into `UpdateIntellisale` method.
Like:

```
class UiUpdate {
    public void UpdateIntellisale(Form1 form) {
        form.Intellisale_Lastprocessed_Item_Label.text = "test";
    }
}
```

And call it like: `UpdateIntellisale(this)` (of course only if `this` is of `Form1` class)

Answer (score 0):

there are several issues:
1. You address your label as if it was defined as a static member of Form1.
   Use the instance name instead. e.g.:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.Intellisale_Lastprocessed_Item_Label.Text = "example" 
// Be aware of an InvalidOperationException with the message, "Control control name accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." that is throw if you use this code.
```

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls

2. Usually the labels are defined private in the designer file.
   The easy way is to declare them public, but it is not a good thing to address a field directly from some other class. Use a Property instead.